# Word file's Table of Contents links broken after save as PDF using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, export-to-pdf, tableofcontents

I want to use excel vba to create a PDF by mail merge data from excel file to a word file.
The mail merge part is doing fine. However, the Table of Contents of the exported PDF file after mail merge was broken. It shows hyperlinks are failed.
Does any one know how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

```
Sub MailMerge1()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim wdocSource As Object

Dim strWorkbookName As String

rlrow = Worksheets("temp_E").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Call SelectRow

On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\eng.docx")

strWorkbookName = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop" & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
wdocSource.Activate

wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
        Name:=strWorkbookName, _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `temp_E$`"

With wdocSource.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = TargetRow - 1
        .LastRecord = TargetRow - 1
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With

wd.Visible = True
wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

wd.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test1.pdf", _
ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
OpenAfterExport:=True, _
OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
DocStructureTags:=True, _
BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
UseISO19005_1:=False

Set wdocSource = Nothing
Set wd = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: fwiw, I ran into this issue years ago and found the only solution was to use the Adobe print driver to create a PDF where the TOC (and other) links were maintained in the output file.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for your reply. That is a good solution. Unfortunately, I cannot provide every user a Adobe print driver.

Comment: Test whether you're able to save it the way you want in the Word application. If yes, one can find the VBA equivalent. If not, then you should ask this in an end-user venue - perhaps someone there knows a trick. Word manages TOC, page numbering and hyperlinks as a complex set of nested field codes. I well imagine something gets lost during conversion... Theoretically, I imagine it would be possible using VBA to work through the TOC, extract the hyperlinks, turn the TOC into plain text, then recreate the hyperlinks on the now-static TOC content. Do you do anything with the TOC after the merge?

Comment: @CindyMeister  I am able to save it to PDF with working TOC in the word application.
You reminded me. Since I do not need the hyperlinks after save as PDF, I used VBA to turn the TOC into plain text and removed all hyperlink formats. It is not a solution but a good work around.

Comment: Glad you at least have a work-around. You might also try recording a macro when saving in the UI, if you're interested in perhaps keeping the hyperlinks. Compare that with your code and see if you can find the difference.

Comment: @CindyMeister  I have tried to record a macro during saving in the UI. So weird, the codes are exactly the same...